# Make Intent.ACTION_VIEW accept multiple URIs

Tags: android

I want to launch some apps which accept geo coordinates (http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). The problem is that they want different URIs.

**Example** (pseudo code):

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addSomeUri("http://maps.google.com/maps/?daddr="+myAddress);
            intent.addSomeUri("http://someotherservice.com/?coordinates="+myLat+":"+myLng+"&address=myAddress");
```

EDIT:
Of course the goal is for both apps to appear in the same activity chooser.
 [image]

**How can I achieve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I achieve it?

Call `startActivity()` (or `startService()` or whatever) once per `Uri`.

Comment: But won't it open two choosers one after another? I want both the apps appear in the same activity chooser.

Comment: @MichałK: "But won't it open two choosers one after another?" -- yes. "I want both the apps appear in the same activity chooser" -- that is only possible if you create your own "activity chooser", via `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.

Comment: And that's my answer (though I really wished it was as straightforward as I put it in my question). Thanks!

Comment: @MichałK: As I commented elsewhere recently, one of these days I will write an extended activity chooser to handle scenarios like this, as this comes up a lot. It just is not an itch that I have needed to scratch just yet.

Comment: I would like to see it. There's more to this than what I described. E.g. situation where I want to provide some text for either email or sms. For an sms I only have content text. For email I also want title. But if I specify title, the sms apps will disappear from the chooser or will make it an mms instead. Etc.

Comment: did you see the new Pocket share dialog? It's beautiful and definitely custom made

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to launch every app?
If not, you have simpler way

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:30.0, 120.0"));
 startActivity(intent);
```